# MenuBar Click Event

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to open a window after menubar click(not menubar item). What is the wrong below code :

```
self.menuHelp.triggered.connect(lambda : HelpWindow().exec_())
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to ask here...If you are getting error, please do post the message...otherwise, explain more.

Comment: Is `HelpWindow` of type `QApplication`? If so, you should probably make it a `QMainWindow` and `.show()` it instead.

Comment: HelpWindow is a class that derived from QDialogBox .

Comment: What is wrong depends on what you see vs what you expect. Clearly, you expect the dialog box to open; but what do you see that doesn't match that? exception traceback? crash? etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right then you want to open new window on a menubar click and [trigger event](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenubar.html#triggered) is different with click event, so You need to implement your own menubar, I have a working example but not sure what is the point of this :)
And some code I took it from above answer, sorry for being lazy.

```
import sys
# This is bad, but was stealing code from above answer
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class HelpWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HelpWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("self")
        self.resize(500, 350)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        textLbl = QtGui.QLabel("REally ?")
        layout.addWidget(textLbl)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def exec_(self):
        super(HelpWindow, self).exec_()
        return "Blaaa"

class CustomMB(QMenuBar):
    mbClick = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomMB, self).__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.mbClick.emit('clicked')

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.main_menu = CustomMB()
        self.main_menu.mbClick.connect(lambda : HelpWindow().exec_())
        self.setMenuBar(self.main_menu)
        self.create_menu()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu2 = self.main_menu.addMenu('Menu 1')

        Action1=QAction('Menu 1 0',self)
        Action1.triggered.connect(self.action_1)
        menu2.addAction(Action1)

        Action2=QAction('Menu 1 1',self)
        Action2.triggered.connect(self.action_2)
        menu2.addAction(Action2)

    def menu_1(self):
        new=MyWindow()
        new.setMinimumSize(320,160)
        new.show()

    def action_1(self):
        print('Menu 1 0')

    def action_2(self):
        print('Menu 1 1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    new=MyWindow()
    new.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: if you put -tive vote please provide the reason you rocket scientists

Comment: I know this is 4 years old but this still works on pyqt5 and it helped me a lot.